# Error clear markers when load ajax again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I using ajax to load markers

```
var markers = [];
function loadMap() {
    var i;
    $.getJSON("loadmarkers.php", function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var result = data.results[i];
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(result.geometry.lat), parseFloat(result.geometry.lng));
            addMarker(latlng); 
        }
    });
}
function addMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
}
```

This is delete all markers

```
function clearMarkers() {
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
}

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="clearMarkers();">Delete</a>
```

When I click Delete markers, it's not work

Comment: Where are you pushing the markers into the `markers` array?

Answer (score 0):

I was find my error. It's work very OK

```
function addMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```